# Mongo query where parameter starts with field value

Tags: mongodb

I have some preference objects like:

```
 {_id: ...,
 group: 'mycode',
 path: '/some/path/'
 value: 123}
```

and I want to do a lookup for all preferences that match a specific URL, e.g. `/some/path/123`

I can't do a `$regex` since the parameter is longer than the field value, so I am looking at doing a `$where` query like:

```
 db.coll.find({group: 'mycode', $where: "'/some/path/123'.indexof(this.path) >= 0"});
```

It feels like there should be a better way of doing this, since it's a basic feature of SQL. Am I missing a better way?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? From what I understand, you are trying to find all preference documents with `path` fields that are a contiguous substring of the query term `/some/path/123`. Is this correct?